# Global CORS config issues between React and SpringBoot application

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, cors

The error I receive:
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/echo. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 403.

I have configured the CorsConfig as below in my SpringBoot part

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class CorsConfig {
    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**")
                    .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
                    .allowedMethods("*")
                    .allowedHeaders("*")
                    .allowCredentials(true);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

But it just doesn't work if I call the localhost:8080 of springboot from my React.

Having said that my method specific CORS config works just fine. The issue is only with Global CORS configuration.

Comment: Check your bean is initialized or not. You may need to add you config class to package scan using `@ComponentScan`

Comment: What is your actual origin and what headers is your server sending back?